# Show that a comparability graph is perfect.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that a comparability graph is perfect.

I'm trying to be able to prove Dilworth's Theorem from perfect graphs.  I'll cite the perfect graph theorem for the complement step.  This is the part that's in my way, it's listed as a problem in Diestel.

Idea: We have the additional structure on the comparability graph that comes from the poset itself.  A sort of orientation.

Thank you!

Comment: It's might be easiest just to prove Dilworth's theorems, they're not that hard.